# SQLite connection doesn't appear in Entity Data Model wizard in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a problem with SQLite and Entity Framework. After connecting to an SQLite database in SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox, I add a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model item, using Database First. 
I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alDxmm7iAB4, but the SQLite connection doesn't appear in "Which data connection should your application use to connect to the database?"

[image: SQLite connection doesn't appear]

I also installed "sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.108.0.exe".
**So how can I connect to SQLite database using ADO.NET Entity Data Model using Database First?**

P/s: Here is SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox - About:
*Version 4.7.534.0 - 1,094,815 downloads
SQL Server Compact 4.0 in GAC - No
SQL Server Compact 4.0 DbProvider - No
SQL Server Compact 4.0 DDEX provider - No
SQL Server Compact 4.0 Simple DDEX provider - Yes
SQL Server Compact 3.5 in GAC - No
SQL Server Compact 3.5 DbProvider - No
SQL Server Compact 3.5 DDEX provider - No
Sync Framework 2.1 SqlCe 3.5 provider - No
SQLite ADO.NET Provider included: 1.0.107.0
SQLite EF6 DbProvider in GAC - Yes
System.Data.SQLite DDEX provider - No
SQLite Simple DDEX provider - Yes*

Comment: You have a mix of version 107 and 108 - everywhere must be the same version - see detailed troubleshooting steps here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider

Comment: @ErikEJ I don't know how to fix that. I installed "sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.108.0.exe", and in the machine.config file has "Version=1.0.108.0". So please help me!